# How can I manipulate multiple div containers using the grid property?

Tags: css

[Four card feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vUDB.jpg)

Essentially what I'm trying to do is make my CSS code manipulate the boxes to the appropriate positions, like in the image. I'm trying to do this with the grid property but I'm stuck.

Comment: If you want to be helped, please share your code

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use grid for this - I would use flexbox instead.

Here is a starter for it:

https://codepen.io/mikode83/pen/abpKMRB

```
<div class="items-wrap container">
    <div class="items-col">
        <div class="item">hello world</div>
    </div>
    <div class="items-col">
        <div class="item">hello world</div>
        <div class="item">hello world</div>
    </div>
    <div class="items-col">
        <div class="item">hello world</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
*, 
*:before, 
*:after {
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: calc(100% - 60px);
}

.items-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: center;
    
    
    .items-col {
        padding: 20px;
        width: 33.333%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
        
        .item {
            margin-bottom: 40px;
            height: 340px;
            background: #000;
            color: #fff;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with grids is, that they are deterministic and you'll need to adjust with media queries. Flexboxes are flexible by nature and adapt. If you have an unknown number of elements grids are a bad idea especially if they should span over multiple rows. This is bad because you will need to do the math. If all you need is single row items then grids are better suited and you'd simply use the `grid-auto-rows`. Property.

The image shows blocks overlapping by around 50% so each block is 2 rows in height and each cell has the same height.

It's not difficult to emulate that behaviour but maintaining proper looks through all resolutions and aspect-ratios is not that easy. The snippet below will need media queries to adjust to certain screen sizes obviously.

Refer to some cheat sheets on the web in terms of CSS grids, i.e. [CSS Cheat Sheet at CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

P.S.: You should post your code so people can tell you where you made a mistake. Otherwise it looks like you couldn't be bothered and someone else should do your work.

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  line-height: 1.32rem;
}

h2,
h3,
h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

h2,
h3 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 3.3rem;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.65rem;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.claim {
  text-align: center;
}

.claim p {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.65rem;
}

.gridContainer {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 2rem;
}

.gridContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.gridItem {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background: grey;
}

.gridItemLeft {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.gridItemRight {
  grid-column-start: 6;
}

.gridItemCenter {
  grid-column-start: 4;
}

.gridItemTop {
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.gridItemMid {
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

.gridItemBottom {
  grid-row-start: 3;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <header class="claim">
    <h3>Reliable, efficient delivery</h3>
    <h2>Powered by Technology</h2>
    <p>Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
  </header>
  <main class="gridContainer">
    <article class="gridItem gridItemMid gridItemLeft">
      <header>
        <h4>Supervisor</h4>
      </header>
      <main>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
      </main>
    </article>
    <article class="gridItem gridItemTop gridItemCenter">
      <header>
        <h4>Team Builder</h4>
      </header>
      <main>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
      </main>
    </article>
    <article class="gridItem gridItemBottom gridItemCenter">
      <header>
        <h4>Karma</h4>
      </header>
      <main>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
      </main>
    </article>
    <article class="gridItem gridItemMid gridItemRight">
      <header>
        <h4>Calculator</h4>
      </header>
      <main>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
      </main>
    </article>
  </main>
</section>
```